# Set focus between prepend and value

Tags: javascript, focus, prepend

Scenario:
A button should prepend dynamic text to a text area that contains value already, then set focus after the text that is added. I cannot succeed in adding focus after between prepended text and previous value..

```
$('#workLogBtn').click(function(){
    // $('textarea[id^="Oppgaver_"]').prepend(timeSignature).focus();

    $('textarea[id^="Oppgaver_"]').val(function(i, text) {
        return timeSignature + text;
    });

    $('#workLogBtn').hide().fadeOut( 1000 );
    $('textarea[id^="Oppgaver_"]').css('margin-top', '63px');
    return false;
  });
```

I have tried both prepend and val(), but it only places focus at the end of the textarea, not after the text is added.

```
$('#workLogBtn').click(function(){
    $('textarea[id^="Oppgaver_"]').prepend(currenttimeStamp + ', ' +  timeStamp.getHoursTwoDigits() + ':' + timeStamp.getMinutesTwoDigits() + ' - '  + signedByUser + ':' + '\r\r\r');
    $('#workLogBtn').hide();
    $('textarea[id^="Oppgaver_"]').css('margin-top', '36px');
    return false;
  });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ys6rjvay/)

The solution below works. But when i add it to the SharePoint site it acts a bit unnatural as to where it places the caret. I cant understand where the count starts. The -3 matters, but if i write -0 it still ends up in the middle of the text.

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oVm5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two functions:

```
function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
  if (input.setSelectionRange) {
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
  } else if (input.createTextRange) {
        var range = input.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
        range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
        range.select();
  }
}

function setCaretToPos(input, pos) {
  setSelectionRange(input, pos, pos);
}
```

and modify your click handler as follows:

```
$('#workLogBtn').click(function(){
    var newString=currenttimeStamp + ', ' +  timeStamp.getHoursTwoDigits() + ':' + timeStamp.getMinutesTwoDigits() + ' - '  + signedByUser + ':' + '\r\r\r';  $('textarea[id^="Oppgaver_"]').prepend(newString);
    $('#workLogBtn').hide();
    $('textarea[id^="Oppgaver_"]').css('margin-top', '36px');
    setCaretToPos($('textarea[id^="Oppgaver_"]')[0], newString.length-1)
    return false;
  });
```

Here is a snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

// CSS:ADD
$('textarea[id^="Oppgaver_"]').css("width", "800px");
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// USER:GET
     var signedInUser = document.getElementById('zz5_Menu').innerHTML;   
     var end = signedInUser.indexOf('<'); 
     var signedByUser = signedInUser.substring();

// DATE:FORMAT
    Date.prototype.getHoursTwoDigits = function(){var retval = this.getHours();if (retval < 10){return ("0" + retval.toString());}else{return retval.toString();}}
    Date.prototype.getMinutesTwoDigits = function(){var retval = this.getMinutes();if (retval < 10){return ("0" + retval.toString());}else{return retval.toString();}}
    var timeStamp = new Date();
    function pad(n) {return n < 10 ? "0"+n : n;}
    var currenttimeStamp = [pad(timeStamp.getDate()), pad(timeStamp.getMonth()+1), timeStamp.getFullYear()].join('.'); 
    var timeSignature = currenttimeStamp + ', ' +  timeStamp.getHoursTwoDigits() + ':' + timeStamp.getMinutesTwoDigits() + ' - '  + signedByUser + ':' + '\r\r\r';

// BUTTON:PREPEND
    $('textarea[id^="Oppgaver_"]').before( '<p><button id="workLogBtn">Signer</button></p>' );

// BUTTON:ACTION
    function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
      if (input.setSelectionRange) {
        input.focus();
        input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
      } else if (input.createTextRange) {
        var range = input.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
        range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
        range.select();
      }
    }
    
    function setCaretToPos(input, pos) {
      setSelectionRange(input, pos, pos);
    }

    $('#workLogBtn').click(function(){
      var newString=currenttimeStamp + ', ' +  timeStamp.getHoursTwoDigits() + ':' + timeStamp.getMinutesTwoDigits() + ' - '  + signedByUser + ':' + '\r\r\r';  $('textarea[id^="Oppgaver_"]').prepend(newString);
        $('#workLogBtn').hide();
        $('textarea[id^="Oppgaver_"]').css('margin-top', '36px');
        setCaretToPos($('textarea[id^="Oppgaver_"]')[0], newString.length-3)
        return false;
      });

});
```

```css
textarea {width:600px;height:600px;border:0px;border-radius:4px;padding:20px;margin:0 0 0 20px;color:#444;}

#workLogBtn, #workLogBtn:visited {padding:4px 10px;text-decoration:none;margin:10px 20px; background:green;color:#fff;border-radius:4px;display:inline-block;border:0px;}
#workLogBtn:hover {color:#444;background:#fff;}
#zz5_Menu {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="zz5_Menu">Eliassen, John-Eilif</a>

<textarea id="Oppgaver_f3cf5190-9ce6-459b-808c-4a832ee9a559_$TextField">
17.03.2017, 10:37 - Eliassen, John-Eilif:
Oppgradering fra v 6.20.3185 til 6.20.3215

17.03.2017, 10:37 - Eliassen, John-Eilif:
Oppgradering fra v 6.20.3185 til 6.20.3215
</textarea>
```

Comment: I hadd to adjust the -3 a bit, because the caret kept ending up in the middle of line below. But this worked awesomely! Thank you Hadas!

Comment: Damnit. When i load the script into prod, newString.length-3 starts the count from the bottom of the textarea, and not at the new line. IE11. In jsfiddle it worx perfectly in IE11, but in prod it doesnt. I will run some debug.